# Image of a real function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis

Let the function  $f:\mathbb{R}\times \left [ -1,1 \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f\left ( x,y \right )=x-\sqrt{1-y^{2}}$.

How to calculate the image of $f$?

I know that the image of $f$ is defined as
 $Imf=\left \{ z\in \mathbb{R}; \exists \left ( x,y \right )\in \mathbb{R}^{2},f\left ( x,y \right )=z\right \}$, but I do not see how to find $z$
Thanks for the help

Comment: Notice that $x$ and $y$ act completely independently here. Try to compute the image of $x$ and $\sqrt{1 - y^2}$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x,1)=x$ which gives us whatever real value we wish, that is to say, for $y\in{\bf{R}}$, then $f(y,1)=y$, where $(y,1)\in{\bf{R}}\times[-1,1]$.